# Unable to evaluate expressions with a reflexive transitive closure

Tags: isabelle

The following expressions are almost identical:

```
value "(1,5) ∈ trancl {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,5)}"
value "(1,5) ∈ rtrancl {(1::nat,2::nat),(2,5)}"
```

However the first one is evaluated fine, and for the second one I get the following error:

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type nat not of sort {enum,equal}
No type arity nat :: enum
```

It seems that the error is caused by the identity relation:

```
value "(1::nat,5::nat) ∈ Id"
```

However the following code lemma doesn't help:

```
lemma Id_code [code]: "(a, b) ∈ Id ⟷ a = b" by simp
```

Could you please suggest how to fix it? Why it doesn't work from the scratch? Is it just an incompleteness of code lemmas or there are more fundamental reasons?

Comment: My guess would be: The transitive closure of a finite relation is itself finite; but the reflexive closure can become an infinite set (if the type is infinite). That's why `rtrancl` demands `enum` sort. (I don't know a lot about `value` and the code lemmas, so I can't write a whole answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem becomes apparent when you look at the code equations for `rtrancl` with `code_thms rtrancl`:

```
rtrancl r ≡ trancl r ∪ Id
```

Here, `Id` is the identity relation, i.e. the set of all `(x, x)`. If your type is infinite, both `Id` and its complement will also be infinite, and there is no way to represent that in a set with the Isabelle code generator's default set representation (which is as lists of either all the elements that are in the set or all the elements that are not in the set).

The code equation for `Id` reflects this as well:

```
Id = (λx. (x, x)) ` set enum_class.enum
```

Here, `enum_class.enum` comes from the `enum` type class and is a list of all values of a type. This is where the `enum` constraint comes from when you try to evaluate `rtrancl`.

I don't think it's possible to evaluate `rtrancl` without modifying the representation of sets in the code generator setup (and even then, printing the result in a readable form would be challenging). However, getting the code generator to evaluate things like `(1, 5) ∈ rtrancl …` is relatively easy: you can simply register a code unfold rule like this:

```
lemma in_rtrancl_code [code_unfold]: "z ∈ rtrancl A ⟷ fst z = snd z ∨ z ∈ trancl A"
  by (metis prod.exhaust_sel rtrancl_eq_or_trancl)
```

Then your `value` command works fine.